Building a Swift XCFramework compatible with Objective-c
I'm building a Swift Package distributed in the form of an XCFramework.
Importing the resulting binary inside a Swift application works just fine, but trying to import it inside of an Objective-c application does not. (file not found or module not found at import statement).
For testing purpose, I just drag n drop the XCFramework into my projects to import it.
What am I missing?
Here is the Swift Package definition:
let package = Package(
    name: "MySDK",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MySDK",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["MySDK"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MySDK"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MySDKTests",
            dependencies: ["MySDK"]),
    ]
)

and here is the build script, using xcodebuild (there is no intermediate Xcode project):
# Build for iOS simulator
xcodebuild \
  -workspace ${WORKSPACE} \
  -scheme ${SCHEME} \
  -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
  -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
  -archivePath "${BUILD_DIR}/archives/${SCHEME}-Simulator" \
  BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR} \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  DEFINES_MODULE=YES \
  SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER=YES \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
  OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-DCOCOAPODS"

# Build for iOS device
xcodebuild \
  -workspace ${WORKSPACE} \
  -scheme ${SCHEME} \
  -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
  -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
  -archivePath "${BUILD_DIR}/archives/${SCHEME}-Device" \
  BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR} \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  DEFINES_MODULE=YES \
  SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER=YES \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
  OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-DCOCOAPODS"

######################
# Create universal xcframework
######################
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/${SCHEME}.framework \
    -framework ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks/${SCHEME}.framework \
    -output ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/${SCHEME}.xcframework

# Add SwiftModules to XCframework
mkdir ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/${SCHEME}.xcframework/ios-arm64/${SCHEME}.framework/Modules
cp -r ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/${SCHEME}.swiftmodule ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/${SCHEME}.xcframework/ios-arm64/${SCHEME}.framework/Modules/

mkdir ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/${SCHEME}.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/${SCHEME}.framework/Modules
cp -r ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/${SCHEME}.swiftmodule ${SCHEME}/${BUILD_DIR}/${SCHEME}.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/${SCHEME}.framework/Modules/



It turns out that, the same way xcodebuild create-xcframework does not copy the .modulemap, it also not not copy the Swift headers.
Here is a working script that copies both from the derived data. It also make it easy to add platforms.
for PLATFORM in "iOS" "iOS Simulator"; do

    case $PLATFORM in
    "iOS")
    RELEASE_FOLDER="Release-iphoneos"
    ;;
    "iOS Simulator")
    RELEASE_FOLDER="Release-iphonesimulator"
    ;;
    esac
    
    ARCHIVE_PATH=$RELEASE_FOLDER

    xcodebuild archive \
        -workspace $WORKSPACE \
        -scheme $SCHEME \
        -destination "generic/platform=$PLATFORM" \
        -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH \
        -derivedDataPath ".build" \
        SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
        BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

    FRAMEWORK_PATH="$ARCHIVE_PATH.xcarchive/Products/usr/local/lib/$SCHEME.framework"
    MODULES_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_PATH/Modules"
    mkdir -p $MODULES_PATH
    
    HEADERS_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_PATH/Headers"
    mkdir -p $HEADERS_PATH

    BUILD_PRODUCTS_PATH=".build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/$SCHEME/BuildProductsPath"
    INTERMEDIATE_BUILD_FILES_PATH=".build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/$SCHEME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath"
    RELEASE_PATH="$BUILD_PRODUCTS_PATH/$RELEASE_FOLDER"
    SWIFT_MODULE_PATH="$RELEASE_PATH/$SCHEME.swiftmodule"
    RESOURCES_BUNDLE_PATH="$RELEASE_PATH/${SCHEME}_${SCHEME}.bundle"

    # Copy Swift modules
    if [ -d $SWIFT_MODULE_PATH ]
    then
        cp -r $SWIFT_MODULE_PATH $MODULES_PATH
    fi
    
    SWIFT_HEADER="$INTERMEDIATE_BUILD_FILES_PATH/$SCHEME.build/$RELEASE_FOLDER/$SCHEME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/$SCHEME-Swift.h"

    if [ -f "$SWIFT_HEADER" ]
    then
       cp -p $SWIFT_HEADER $HEADERS_PATH || exit -2
    fi

    # Copy resources bundle, if exists
    if [ -e $RESOURCES_BUNDLE_PATH ]
    then
        cp -r $RESOURCES_BUNDLE_PATH $FRAMEWORK_PATH
    fi
    
done

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
  -framework Release-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/usr/local/lib/$SCHEME.framework \
  -framework Release-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/usr/local/lib/$SCHEME.framework \
  -output $SCHEME.xcframework

